# Getting RGB occurrence count in percentage from a python list (searching of best method)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-2.6

What is the best way to perform below actions

1. find whether the given image is plain or it holds some drawing/graphics.
2. which pixel value(RGB) has been used maximum in a given image.

   ```
   i1 = list(self.__img1.getdata())
   result=0
   resultVal=None
   a = list(set(i1))
   length = len(i1)

   for val in a:
       print val
       occurencePercent = (i1.count(val) / length) * 100
       if occurencePercent > result:
           result = occurencePercent
           resultVal=val
   print resultVal
   print result
   ```

But since its  640 x 480 it just takes very high time..so what is the best approach..Please guide

Comment: What does your code look so far? How are you currently trying it, and what errors do you get?

Comment: @usethedeathstar : added the example code which i am trying to work

Comment: Please, use 'named' variables to let us understand their meaning at a glance (e.g. 'a' is not a good name for a list of unique RGB values)

Comment: I would suggest profiling and figuring out what is the slowest part (converting getdata() to a list, creating a set and converting it to a list, i1.count(val), etc). You might also want to look into numpy for this if possible.

Comment: i1.count(val)/length if you use 2.6, that is int division, so 5/9 will give 100% in that case, while it should be something like 56% - just thought id mention that bug in your code

Comment: @usethedeathstar :: very true got really stuck there...posted my currrent solution below..request your view on that

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution i arrived for now.But if there some more smarter methods please advice

```
    i1 = list(self.__img1.getdata())
    UniqOccurenceData={}
    for tempVal in itertools.groupby(i1):
        UniqOccurenceData[tempVal[0]] = len(list(tempVal[1]))
    maxrgboccurence=max(UniqOccurenceData.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    maxVal = float(maxrgboccurence[1])
    maxPercent=float(maxVal/len(i1)) * 100
    print maxrgboccurence
```

Comment: maxval = float() is the cast you need, if the line after it, you divide a float by an int, the result will still be a float, also if you multiply by 100, so the maxPercent = float(maxVal/len(i1)) is not needed to cast to float there, sicne maxval is already a float. Other than that, i didnt check the solution yet